# Error in opening file name with file name as a char in a different fuction

Tags: c, file

I am trying to create a function where a file with a fie name which is stored as a char will save the details entered. However, even though I'm able to get the code to compile, the file name isn't being saved as the file name that I'm entering and in the files there are other random symbols stored along with my data. Could someone tell me what's the error i th code? Here is what I've done-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 25
#define NUM_EMP 3
typedef struct Employees {
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int id;
    char dependents[3][20];
} employee;
void printEmployees (employee emp[NUM_EMP], int c);

int main()
{
    employee emp[3];
    printf("Enter %d Employee details-\n", NUM_EMP);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EMP; i++) {
        printf("Enter %d employee first name-", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", emp[i].fname);
        printf("Enter %d employee last name-", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", emp[i].lname);
        printf("Enter %d employee id-", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &emp[i].id);
        printf("Enter %d Employee dependent names-\n", i + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%s", emp[i].dependents[j]);
        }
    }
        printf("Enter name of file you want to save this in-");
        char Fname[SIZE];
        scanf("%s", &Fname[SIZE]);
        int a;
        saveEmployees(emp, a, Fname);
   
}
void saveEmployees (employee emp[NUM_EMP], int c, char Fname[SIZE])
{
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(&Fname, "w");
    if (fptr== NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile not found");

    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(emp, sizeof(struct Employees), 3, fptr);
        printf("\nData is stored successfully");
        fclose(fptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fptr = fopen(&Fname, "w");` -->> `fptr = fopen(Fname, "w");`

Comment: @wildplasser I tried that too but when I was entering Fname without the & I kept getting "File not found".

Comment: `scanf("%s", &Fname[SIZE] );` is wrong, too.